# How difficult is homomorphic encryption?

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption

I want to learn more about homomorphic encryption and eventually make a career from it. Currently, I'm thinking to have my bachelor degree in this field. What background should I have  for this ? How good at maths should I be? Are there any tests, challenges I can take, programs I can imagine, write, anything I can read to discover if I am suited for it?

Comment: very subjective and open ended question

Comment: "How good at maths should I be?"  Well, if you're going to be dealing with how homomorphic primitives work, you need to be quite comfortable with "maths".

Comment: "Maths" is just the Commonwealth version of "math" for Americans. Same thing, different dialect.

OP, you want a degree in abstract algebra/number theory. Then a PHD. Then specialize in homomorphic encryption in postdoc, it's too small a niche currently to be a full PHD program on its own.

Comment: FHE is a very specific research topic, not a career path (in the business world). Right now, FHE does not exist outside of research programs. And it comes with the territory, that any serious contribution to the field is surely at the doctoral level (PhD students at the very least). If you don't plan to go that far in academia, this goal might not be ideal. About the math: It is far more complex than anything you would learn up to your bachelor degree.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the people dealing in homomorphic encryption are at the forefront of applied mathematical research (Shai, Smart, Gentry, Boneh...).  So world-class certainly wouldn't hurt!

Pick up a paper cited by HELib (for one example starting place), read it.  Fail to understand it, find a cited paper, read it... repeat until eventually you find a text book instead of a cited paper.  Better yet, just start from Shoup's number theory book freely available online.